# how Suzuki algorithm is applied to cv::findContour function in opencv?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv

I read Suzuki paper for searching how cv::findContour function find contour border but I cannot find how Suzuki algorithm is applied to findContour.
NBD, -NBD(newest border number) why -NBD is used? and how to prepare if one border overlaps another?

Comment: One of the cool thing of OpenCV is that is Open Source, thus the algorithm's code is visible for everyone to check it out. [Here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp#L1885) is the link to the function.

Comment: I  could search what i want to know about function.  but i could not find the reason why the algorithm uses -nbd(newest border number). OpenCV code just used -nbd but they do not explaing the reason. I think contours can be detected only using nbd