# findContours function in OpenCV, why it uses -nbd(newest border number)?

Tags: opencv, contour, labeling

I have a question that why findContours function uses -nbd(newest border number) in following border. I searched Suzuki theory for searching details which is applying to findContours function.

[image]

But Suzuki theroy explain nbd is 'left' value, -nbd is 'right' value and it is only based on existing theory. And the problem is i cannot find the original theory. Anybody genius answer me please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how Suzuki algorithm is applied to cv::findContour function in opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48336513/how-suzuki-algorithm-is-applied-to-cvfindcontour-function-in-opencv)

Comment: Do not ask duplicated questions, just edit the previous question with the new information and it will be shown at the top...